# how to pass the id into the getElementById() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

have javascript code where i have the function to validate the required field(for each field one one function).My problem is i want only method where i can just pass the ID to validate the required field and corresponding field has to style based on error .I mean if it doesn't have any value do make the field as red colour and if user enter then colour has to change .

Comment: You seem to be passing the id into `getElementById()` quite well. Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is the problem with your current code and any errors it produces.

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem with your validate function. You are passing the DOM element into the validate function, but then using it as a string.

```
function validate(x){
  // Validation rule
  if(x.value ==""){     
    x.style.background ='#e35152';
    x.focus();
  }
   if(x.value !=""){
    x.style.background ='#ccffcc';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged jquery I am suggesting you to try below solution of jquery:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/nnwf7akx/)**

```
$('input.req').on('blur',function(){
    if($(this).val()=="")
    {
        $(this).removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        $(this).parent().children('span.err-text').text('Required');
    }
    else
    {
    $(this).removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        $(this).parent().children('span.err-text').text('');
    }
});
```

Now on your `validateForm()` just trigger the blur event as below:

```
$('input.req').trigger('blur');
```

and this will call your required validation!! 
 Let me know if any doubt!!

**Update:**

Updated as per your requirement!! Here is the **[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/nnwf7akx/3/)**

Below is your updated event

```
$('input.req').on('blur',function(){
     if($(this).val()=="")
     {
          $(this).removeClass('success').addClass('error').attr('placeholder',$(this).attr('placeholder')+ ' - Required');
     }
     else
     {
          $(this).removeClass('error').addClass('success');
     }
});
```

Comment: its working .But how to put the text 'Required' as placeholder on the input box

Comment: @SnehasishDas In your `input` control there will be a property called `placeholder` as I've shown in fiddle!! Just put it there ex - `placeholder="First Name - Required"`

Comment: thanks for reply Guruprasad  but i want before validation place holder is like 'First Name' and after validation that place holder has to update like 'First Name - Required' but not in span tag

Comment: @SnehasishDas.. Updated answer with demo!!

Comment: thanks alot Guruprasad